# NumberFormat Error Causing App to Crash Android When Taking Data Inputs From EditText

Tags: android, parsing, crash, android-edittext, number-formatting

I'm trying to get user input and then parse them to doubles. I've even added in a way to check if they're null and then set them to 0, but it's still crashing and giving me the error.

Here is my code:

```
package com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

public class CarbonCalcActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //household energy
    double electricity;
    double naturalGas;
    double fuelOil;
    double propane;

    EditText elecunit;
    EditText elecbill;
    EditText gasunit;
    EditText gasbill;
    EditText fuelunit;
    EditText fuelbill;
    EditText propunit;
    EditText propbill;
    //transportation
    double vehicle1;
    double vehicle2;
    double vehicle3;
    double publicTransport;//.42*number of miles
    double airTravel;

    EditText v1mpw;
    EditText v1mpg;
    EditText v2mpw;
    EditText v2mpg;
    EditText v3mpw;
    EditText v3mpg;
    EditText pub;
    EditText air;
    //food
    double totalFood;
    double meatFishEggs;
    double cerealBakery;
    double dairy;
    double fruitVegetable;
    double eatingOut;
    double otherFoods;

    EditText meat;
    EditText cer;
    EditText da;
    EditText fv;
    EditText out;
    EditText otherf;
    //services and goods
    double totalSG;
    double clothing;
    double furnishHousehold;
    double otherGoods;
    double services;

    double total;

    EditText sg;
    EditText cloth;
    EditText furn;
    EditText otherg;
    EditText serv;
    Button submit;

    List<double[]> dataValues;

    Context activity;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_carbon_calc);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        /*
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score), newHighScore);
        editor.commit();*/

        activity = CarbonCalcActivity.this;

        dataValues= new ArrayList<double[]>();

        submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitb);

    }

    public void onBtnClicked(View v){
        if(v.getId() == R.id.submitb){
            elecunit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.kwh);
            elecbill = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.elec);
            if(elecunit != null && elecbill != null) {
                electricity = (Integer.parseInt(elecbill.getText().toString())/Integer.parseInt(elecunit.getText().toString()))*1.37*12;

            }
            else
                electricity = 0;

            gasunit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cf);
            gasbill = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.gas);

            if(gasunit != null && gasbill != null) {
                naturalGas = (Integer.parseInt(gasbill.getText().toString())/Integer.parseInt(gasunit.getText().toString()))*120.61*12;

            }
            else
                naturalGas = 0;

            fuelunit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fogal);
            fuelbill = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fo);

            if(fuelunit != null && fuelbill != null) {
                fuelOil = (Integer.parseInt(fuelbill.getText().toString())/Integer.parseInt(fuelunit.getText().toString()))*22.37*12;

            }
            else
                fuelOil = 0;

            propunit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.progal);
            propbill = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pro);

            if(propunit != null && propbill != null) {
                propane = (Integer.parseInt(propbill.getText().toString())/Integer.parseInt(propunit.getText().toString()))*12.17*12;

            }
            else
                propane = 0;

            v1mpg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.v1mpg);
            v1mpw = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.v1mpw);

            if(v1mpg != null && v1mpw != null) {
                vehicle1 = ((Integer.parseInt(v1mpw.getText().toString())*52)/(Integer.parseInt(v1mpg.toString()))*19.4*(100/95));
            }
            else {
                vehicle1 = 0;
            }

            v2mpg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.v2mpg);
            v2mpw = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.v2mpw);

            if(v2mpg != null && v2mpw != null) {
                vehicle2 = ((Integer.parseInt(v2mpw.getText().toString())*52)/Integer.parseInt(v2mpg.toString()))*19.4*(100/95);
            }
            else {
                vehicle2 = 0;
            }

            v3mpg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.v3mpg);
            v3mpw = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.v3mpw);

            if(v3mpg != null && v3mpw != null) {
                vehicle3 = ((Integer.parseInt(v3mpw.getText().toString())*52)/Integer.parseInt(v3mpg.toString()))*19.4*(100/95);
            }
            else {
                vehicle3 = 0;
            }

            pub = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pubmpy);

            if(pub != null) {
                publicTransport = (Integer.parseInt(pub.toString()))*.42;

            }
            else
                publicTransport = 0;

            air = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.airmpy);

            if(air != null) {
                airTravel = (Integer.parseInt(air.toString()))*223*1.2*1.9*.0022;

            }
            else
                airTravel = 0;

            meat = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.meat);

            if(meat != null) {
                meatFishEggs = (Integer.parseInt(meat.toString()))*1452*12*.0022;

            }
            else
                meatFishEggs = 0;

            cer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cereal);

            if(cer != null) {
                cerealBakery = (Integer.parseInt(cer.toString()))*741*12*.0022;

            }
            else
                cerealBakery = 0;

            da = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dairy);

            if(da != null) {
                dairy = (Integer.parseInt(cer.toString()))*1911*12*.0022;

            }
            else
                dairy = 0;

            fv = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fruit);

            if(fv != null) {
                fruitVegetable = (Integer.parseInt(fv.toString()))*1176*12*.0022;

            }
            else
                fruitVegetable = 0;

            out = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.out);

            if(out != null) {
                eatingOut = (Integer.parseInt(out.toString()))*368*12*.0022;

            }
            else
                eatingOut = 0;

            otherf = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.otherf);

            if(otherf != null) {
                otherFoods = (Integer.parseInt(otherf.toString()))*467*12*.0022;

            }
            else
                otherFoods = 0;

            totalFood = meatFishEggs+cerealBakery+dairy+fruitVegetable+eatingOut+otherFoods;

            cloth = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cloth);

            if(cloth != null) {
                clothing = (Integer.parseInt(cloth.toString()))*436*12*.0022;

            }
            else
                clothing = 0;

            furn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.furnish);

            if(furn != null) {
                furnishHousehold = (Integer.parseInt(furn.toString()))*459*12*.0022;

            }
            else
                furnishHousehold = 0;

            otherg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.otherg);

            if(otherg != null) {
                otherGoods = (Integer.parseInt(otherg.toString()))*338*12*.0022;

            }
            else
                otherGoods = 0;

            serv = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.serv);

            if(serv != null) {
                services = (Integer.parseInt(serv.toString()))*178*12*.0022;

            }
            else
                services = 0;

            totalSG = clothing + furnishHousehold + otherGoods + services;

            Date currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

            double[] currentData = new double[26];

            currentData[0] = currentTime.getMonth();
            currentData[1] = currentTime.getDate();
            currentData[2] = currentTime.getYear();
            currentData[3] = electricity;
            currentData[4] = naturalGas;
            currentData[5] = fuelOil;
            currentData[6] = propane;
            currentData[7] = electricity;
            currentData[8] = vehicle1;
            currentData[9] = vehicle2;
            currentData[10] = vehicle3;
            currentData[11] = publicTransport;
            currentData[12] = airTravel;
            currentData[13] = totalFood;
            currentData[14] = meatFishEggs;
            currentData[15] =cerealBakery;
            currentData[16] = dairy;
            currentData[17] = fruitVegetable;
            currentData[18] = eatingOut;
            currentData[19] = otherFoods;
            currentData[20] = totalSG;
            currentData[21] = clothing;
            currentData[22] = furnishHousehold;
            currentData[23] = otherGoods;
            currentData[24] = services;

            total = 0;

            for(int i = 3; i < 25; i++)
            {
                total = total + currentData[i];
            }

            currentData[25] = (total/2000);

        }
    }
```

Here is my log:

```
08-31 18:51:25.778 17735-17735/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp 
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp, PID: 17735

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for 
android:onClick

at 
android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener
.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)

at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6219)

at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24482)

at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:769)

at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)

at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)

at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6540)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener
.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)

at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6219) 

at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24482) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:769) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6540) 
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) 
                                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
                                                                                     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:620)
                                                                                     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:643)
                                                                                     at com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp.CarbonCalcActivity.onBtnClicked(CarbonCalcActivity.java:115)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                                                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6219) 
                                                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24482) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:769) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6540) 
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

I'm not sure about the exact cause of this, especially since I did all the checking for null. Can someone please help resolve the error? Thanks!
    elecunit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.kwh);
                elecbill = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.elec);

```
            String elecunitString = elecunit.getText().toString();
            String elecbillString = elecbill.getText().toString();

            if(elecunitString != "" && elecbillString != "") {
                electricity = (Integer.parseInt(elecbill.getText().toString())/Integer.parseInt(elecunit.getText().toString()))*1.37*12;

            }
            else
                electricity = 0;
```

Comment: apply proper validations for String which you catch from EditText before Parse to Integer, in your case string might be empty.

Answer (score 0):

What I have noticed is the one that you are checking for null is the EditText itself and not the value of the EditText.. you are doing it like..

```
 EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
 if(editText != null) {
     value = Double.parseDouble(editText.getText().toString());
 } else {
     value = 0;
 }
```

So the proper way to check the value of edittext.. do it like this

```
 EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
 String etString = editText.getText().toString();
 if(etString.equals("")) {
     value = Double.parseDouble(etString);
 } else {
     value = 0;
 }
```

And also check if the string can be converted because maybe you are converting a letter and you will get a NumberFormatException so you can do something like this

```
private double parseStringToDouble(String sVal) {
    if(!sVal.equals("")) {
            try {
                return Double.parseDouble(sVal);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                //will handle the exception
                return 0;
            }
    }
    else return 0;
}
```

And in getting value from your edittext

```
EditText et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et1);
value1 = parseStringToDouble(et1.getText().toString());

EditText et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et2);
value2 = parseStringToDouble(et2.getText().toString());
```

Comment: I added in your initial recommendations and also changed the EditText to only show the number pad when getting inputs so letters cannot be inputted. However, I'm still getting the same error. I added my new code to the original question.

Comment: Is it IllegalStateException? Can I see your xml?

Comment: Please check again.. This is what you're doing..
 if(elecunitString != "" && elecbillString != "") 

Since you are checking a string.. you should use

 if(elecunitString.equals("") && elecbillString.equals(""))